# How to filter by Selected Objects in eCognition?

Tags: classification, ecognition

I was wondering if there is any options in eCognition Developer to filter by selected objects. Suppose if I select some objects with polygon selection tool and want to use *'assign class'*. In the algorithm windows I will set selected objects as *'filter'* so that the algorithm will only work in the objects I selected previously.

I can do this by assigning a new class (ie. test class) to all those objects and filter by *'test class'*, but I want to skip this tedious step. Besides this will blend all other classes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not an exact solve of my problem but I am satisfied with the result until now.

[image]

I used Manual Classification algorithm to brush and change object classes. The class in the 'filter' parameter is the domain effected by the classification (notice the actual 'domain' is set to execute). The 'class' parameter determines to which class will it convert to.

Answer (score 0):

You may solved this issue by using manual classification. But you can clear this issue when using 'Assign class' algorithm.

In the 'class filter' drop down, select 'Unclassified' and run the assign class with your previous setting.

Try this and let me know.

Comment: The 'class filter' in 'assign class' will limit the effective domain in 'unclassified' objects all over the image. I just needed a hand selected domain to work with.

Comment: Then go ahead with manual classification